# web parser url re.findall()

Tags: python, parsing

I'm working on web parser.

I'm supposed ot use regular expressions to parser by following things.
Those are the results.

```
ex) location.href = "login/html";
ex) location.href = "featureId/html";
```

I want to get the all String results, but I coudn't get them.

The code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
import re

url_reg= re.compile('(location\.(href|assign|replace)|window\.location)\s*(=|\()+.*(;|$)')
url ='http://zero.webappsecurity.com/'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
res = urllib2.urlopen(request)
html = res.read().decode('utf-8')

print html
print re.findall(url_reg, html)
```

Run out the source of the result is as follows:

```
[(u'location.href', u'href', u'=', u';'), (u'location.href', u'href', u'=', u';'), (u'location.href', u'href', u'=', u';'), (u'location.href', u'href', u'=', u';'), (u'location.href', u'href', u'=', u';'), (u'location.href', u'href', u'=', u';')]
```

originally, I paln to get as follws.

```
location.href = path + "login" + ".html";
location.href = path + featureId + ".html";
location.href = "/" + "online-banking" + ".html";
location.href = path + featureName +".html";
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: It looks like your string is missing.

Comment: Please let me know what strings are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't describe your question clearly.  Here are strings you want, right?

```
window.location.href = path + "login" + ".html";
window.location.href = path + featureId + ".html";
window.location.href = "/" + "online-banking" + ".html";
window.location.href = path + featureName +".html";
window.location.href = link.page;
window.location.href = path + link.page + ".html";
```

Then you should use patterns like this.

```
...
url_reg= re.compile('window\.location\.href = ["/ +\-\.; a-zA-Z]*')
print url_reg.findall(html)
...
```